# Combination Problem using generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Having 20 distinct balls and 4 distinct baskets, i can put 3 to 9 balls to those baskets(each basket) that is my limitation, so i thought solving this using generating functions, so i applied an exponential function since they are distinct which is $$(\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^6}{6!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}+\frac{x^8}{8!}+\frac{x^9}{9!})^4$$

Then I had to find the coeficient of $\frac {x^{20}}{20!}$
Everything correct so far?

So here my real problem begins: Each basket have specific positions, each ball now takes a number (I envision it like some  separate ticket) and its ball 'sits' in successive positions starting from the 1st one position/place.

So if I understood correctly the second problem is like the 1st but they are permutations now so my function becomes(?):

$$(\frac{3!x^3}{3!}+\frac{4!x^4}{4!}+\frac{5!x^5}{5!}+\frac{6!x^6}{6!}+\frac{7!x^7}{7!}+\frac{8!x^8}{8!}+\frac{9!x^9}{9!})^4$$

because if order matters, and I choose ie $4$ then those $4$ have $4!$ to be placed.Coefficient for this one is $\frac{20!x^{20}}{20!}$

Comment: It looks ask fine except the last bit: You are still using and egf so you want the coefficient of $x^{20}/20!$. I am assuming that this is equivalent to counting the number of ways of lining up 20 children in 4 lines in front of 4 teachers, each line containing at least 3 and at most 9 children. I confess that I find the description in the middle regarding labelling balls that are *already distinct* a bit confusing so perhaps this isn't what you mean after all.

Comment: an analogy using the children-teachers example, the children are sitting to chairs that have numbers and in each class the teacher gives numbers for those seats (starting from 1), so i count how many permutations(?) can 3 to 9 children sits like (so 1 permutetion would be timmy taking number-chair #1 or another one time he takes chair 2) and so on for every child...

Comment: That sounds like the same thing to me. In which case I would say that you want the $x^{20}/20!$ coefficient of $\left(\sum_{k=3}^{9}x^k\right)^4$.